# I get an error when using REGEXP_LIKE statement in my code

Tags: teradata

I have a field in my table called `to_ref`.

When I use `where REGEXP_LIKE(to_ref,'[0-9]{16}')` I get an error

> 3706 - Data Type "to_ref" does not match a defined data type

It has been defined as `Varchar(100)`. It is 16 characters long and should only contain numeric data.

Any help will be appreciated. Even if there is another way to check that the field only contains digits

Answer (score 0):

There's no function name `REGEXP_LIKE` in Teradata (probably Oracle syntax), but REGEXP_SIMILAR:

```
where REGEXP_SIMILAR(to_ref,'[0-9]{16}') = 1
```

As there's no Boolean datatype in Teradata, this returns 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE